# sliding window median of correlations of a matrix

Tags: median, sliding-window, julia

Question parts:

1. Is there a "julia way" to implement a sliding window?
2. What is needed in julia to ignore `NaN`s?

There is a matrix with 264 recording points (rows) and 200 time points (columns). I want to get the median correlation of each recording point with every other point over a 10 sample window.

I've tried this the matlab-way (tm) by creating a 3d 264x264x10 matrix where the third dim is the correlation for that window. In matlab, I would do `median(cors,3)` much like julia can do `mean(cors,3)`. But median does not have support for this. It looks like `mapslices(median,cors,3)` might be what I want, but some recording points have NaNs. In R, I might look to `na.omit()` or function options like `na.ignore=T` But I don't see that for julia.

```
#oned=readdlm("10152_20111123_preproc_torque.1D")
oned=rand(200,264); oned[:,3]=NaN; oned[:,200]=NaN
windows=10
samplesPerWindow=size(oned,1)/windows
cors=zeros(size(oned,2),size(oned,2),windows)
for i=1:windows
 startat=(i-1)*windows+1
 endat=i*windows
 corofsamples=cor(oned[startat:i*windows,:])
 cors[:,:,i]= corofsamples
end
med = mapslices(median,cors,3) # fail b/c NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach, which uses functions to encapsulate parts of the task. By creating a specialized version of the median function that ignores `NaN`, it's easier to use `mapslices`:

```
function findcors(oned, windows)
    samplesPerWindow = size(oned, 1) / windows

    cors = zeros(size(oned, 2), size(oned, 2), windows)

    for i = 1:windows
        startat = (i - 1) * samplesPerWindow + 1
        endat = i * samplesPerWindow
        corofsamples = cor(oned[startat:endat, :])
        cors[:, :, i] = corofsamples
    end

    return cors
end

function nanmedian(A)
    cleanA = A[isfinite(A)]
    if isempty(cleanA)
        NaN
    else
        return median(cleanA)
    end
end

oned = rand(200, 264)
oned[:, 3] = NaN
oned[:, 200] = NaN

cors = findcors(oned, 10)

med = mapslices(nanmedian, cors, 3)
```

I believe your original code was using the wrong window length inside the main loop. Hopefully I've fixed that.

The DataFrames package provides an `NA` value and tools to ignore `NA`, but still needs to clean up its `median` function to exploit those tools.